# Issue with serving images from express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have issues with serving .png image from my express app. I think there is something wrong with the router setup, because it tries to render page rather than serve a static file. The setup is as follows:

```
// app.js
// Module dependencies
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    session = require('./middlewares/session');

// Create server
var app = module.exports = app ? app : express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view options', { layout: true });

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.errorHandler());
app.use(express.responseTime());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(app.router);

var routes = require('./routes')(app);

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// Start server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    console.log(__dirname);
});
```

Then my routes file looks like this:

```
// routes.js    
module.exports = function(app) {
        //Routes
        // app.get('/', routes.index);
        app.get('/api/places', places);

        app.get('/add-review', review);
        app.get('/logout', logout);
        app.get('/:location?/:category?', session(app), routes.index);
    }
```

The jade view where I'm trying to load an image

```
# view
img(src="/nodeapp/img/logo-white.png")
```

I'm using reverse proxy for node app which root is this `http://app.com/nodeapp`

The folder structure:

```
public
   components
   css
   img
   js
server
   srs
      views
      app.js
   test
```

The error that I'm getting is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'logo-white.png' of undefined
    at Object.get_listings (/app/server/src/models/vendors.js:354:16)
    at exports.index (/app/server/src/handlers/index.js:6:31)
    at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at /app/server/src/middlewares/session.js:13:5
    at /app/bbe/server/src/api.js:18:3
    at _fulfilled (/app/node_modules/requestify/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/app/requestify/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/app/node_modules/requestify/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /app/node_modules/requestify/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/app/node_modules/requestify/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
GET /img/logo-white.png 500 857ms
```

So, here it's trying to actually render my jade views rather than serving from a static folder. Other static files such as js and css are served fine. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

=== Edit (added function that renders views) ===

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {  
    res.locals.location = data().get_location(req.params);  
    res.locals.categories =  data().get_categories(res.locals.location);  
    res.locals.listings = data().get_listings(res.locals.location, req.params.category);  

    var meta = {  
        title: "My app",  
        module: "/nodeapp/js/core/index/main.js"  
    };  

    res.render('nodeapp/index', meta);  
};
```

Comment: Can you post the route function that renders the view?

Comment: @Daiwei, I added function in the description of the thread. Thanks!

Comment: I think your `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));` is not picking up `/img/logo-white.png`. Can you try to change `../../public` to `public`?

Comment: You mean `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); `like this?

Comment: Yes. Assuming your `app.js` file is at the same level with `public` directory.

Comment: No, it's not. I have `public` and `server` directories and `app.js` resides in `server > src > app.js`

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `DEBUG=send` then launching your app. That should give you some info from the `send` module which is the implementation of the static middleware. Your reverse proxy setup looks to be correct based on `GET /img/logo-white.png`. If your snippet of directory structure is actually correct, then your root path for the static middleware looks correct. I would start confirming that A) the static middleware does actually get invoked for this request then B) why does it end up calling `next()` without responding.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble myself with setting the 'views' path, so maybe the issue is the same.

I would try to set different view paths for the different sites I had like so (per app)

```
// site1.js
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/site1');

// site2.js
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/site2');
```

For some reason, it just wouldn't find the views to render.  So, I had to set them all back to just '/views' directory, and when I rendered them, I included the extra directory there, and that worked.

I'm thinking if you restructured your directories so this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));
```

becomes

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

that it might start working for you.  I'm assuming all the other things in your public directories aren't being handled right either.  If it's just that png file...check the name, rename it, fiddle with it.

Comment: If the root of your node url is http://app.com/nodeapp, and the error is GET /img/logo-white.png 500, that means it's trying to get the image from http://app.com/img/logo-white.png, is this correct?